# How to create SAML account with google and Cognito?

Tags: saml-2.0, amazon-cognito, google-admin-sdk

How can I integrate the Cognito SAML authentication with google admin saml authentication?

Comment: You can visit the documentations by [github](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-mobile-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/User-Sign-in.rst) and [a post from google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en) to help you identify what essentials you are be needing.